# How to stop the 'live' mic sound playing through the speakers?

Tags: windows-xp, audio, speakers, microphone

I have an old Toshiba Laptop (Satellite 1900-03) running Windows XP. I recently bought a little microphone to plug into the mic port but discovered that the sound is being fed live through the speakers causing feedback.

My question is how do I stop the 'live' microphone sound being piped instantly through the speakers without normal sound still being played?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you mean that the microphone sound is being played back through the speakers constantly.

Try the following:

> Go to the **Control Panel**, and click on **Sounds and Audio Devices**.
>   Under **Device volume**, click on **Advanced**.
>   Under **Microphone**, check the **Mute** button.

If the "Microphone" section is missing, go to Options -> Properties, and under the Playback section, enable it.

Comment: I don't want to mute the mic. The reason I added it is to sometimes record sound for various reasons. I want it available at a moments notice so would rather not mute it until needed - easier to just plug it in when needed but still doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: You're not muting it, recording will work.  You're just muting it from looping back through your speakers.

Comment: Yes, you're right - that's fixed it. No feedback yet I can still record and the speakers still work. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you have Windows XP:

1. Open the *Control Panel*
2. Select *Sounds and Audio Devices ⇨ Audio Tab*
3. Go to *Volume on Sound Recording*
4. Select `Advance` under `Microphone` and check the **Do not monitor** check-box.

This way, you should be able to keep using the microphone without feedback from any speakers.

---

**Update For Windows 10 or Windows 7 issue:**

The tick from "Listen to this device" should be off.
It implies, that Windows is making live monitoring of your commands, may be.
You can still use your mic in applications and will not hear your mic in headphones/speakers.

[image]

Comment: I do have Windows XP but don't have the '1 Do Not Monitor' option. Perhaps it requires the laptop to have an internal Mic and I don't have one?

Answer (score 0):

Read ["How to Eliminate Feedback"](http://www.mediacollege.com/audio/howto/feedback.html). 
The best suggestion seems to distance your mic from the speakers ...

Comment: Can't do that I'm afraid as the mic is a stubby little job and the 'mic in' port is very close to the LHS speaker.